# How to register custom Telemetry in AzureFunction to have additional custom property

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

My application is function azure and included following stuff for custom telemetry request to log additional fields:

```
public class CustomTelemetry : ITelemetryInitializer
{
    public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
    {
        var requestTelemetry = telemetry as RequestTelemetry;
        if (requestTelemetry == null) return;
        requestTelemetry.Properties.Add("LoggedInUserName", "DummyUser");

    }
}
```

Where should I include below code as this is function azure and don't have global.asax startup.

```
   TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers
    .Add(new CustomTelemetry());
```

Which is the common initial setup place  in function azure to register this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in static constructor of your function

```cs
public static class Functions
{
    static Functions()
    {
        TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new CustomTelemetry());
    }

    // Your function goes here
}
```

Comment: ok, do you mean in function azure to create one static function, static constructor and no need to call Functions explicitly. is it ?

Comment: Yes, correct, same as usual - but add the constructor as above

Comment: It did not work . Is it mean, that has to set somewhere else in function app ?